# Populate AJAX success function into a div on another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        success: function() {
        $.get("getuser.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(pmName), function(data) {
          $('txtHint').html(data);        
        });
        }
    });
```

and it processes, but it's not doing what I want.

I've created a cookie on my php page, then brought it into the JavaScript page, so the end result is something like `getuser.php?q=John%Doe`

here's what the layout looks like now.  The user begins by loading ajaxtest.php, then using a drop-down menu, selects a user, which populates into a DIV on ajaxtest.php with the information from `getuser.php?q=John%Doe`

```
|_______________________________|
|          ajaxtest.php         |
|                               |
|   _______#DIV____________     |
|   |    getuser.php       |    |
|   |                      |    |
|   |                      |    |
|   |______________________|    |
|_______________________________|
```

When I ACTION something on getuser.php, the AJAX call above lets me run `update.php,` which contains all my SQL queries, without the user being redirected to this `update.php` page.  Cool.  What I need however is for the CHANGES that the user makes to the database to be instantly refreshed after a successful submit.

I tried doing that with:

```
success: function() {
        $.get("getuser.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(pmName), function(data) {
          $('txtHint').html(data);        
        });
        }
```

that was suggested to me in another post, but I don't see how this code refers BACK to my ajaxtest.php page where this `txtHint` DIV is located.  I feel like I understand the logic of what this statement is doing (get the `getuser.php?q=John%Doe` page, then return it to the `txtHint` DIV) - at least I think that's what it's saying, but I am missing something critical and I'm not sure what it is.  I've looked online for an answer (as I really do want to learn this,) but I don't know the exact thing to search for to find an overview or a tutorial that could teach me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is, but why would you do an ajax call in the success function of your ajax call? Just do one and have it return everything you need all at once.

Comment: So then how do I refresh the database on getuser.php?q=Name without refreshing ajaxtest.php?

Answer (score 0):

You need something more like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'getuser.php',
    data: 
    {
        'q': encodeURIComponent(pmName),
        'r': Math.random()
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) 
    {
      $('txtHint').html(data);        
    }
});
```

Your terminology is all wrong.  You don't "refresh" ajax.  Ajax is like going to a page in a browser, only Javascript is doing that in the backend and returning the page to you in the `data` variable to your success method.  You should say you "call" it or make a "request" to the server with ajax.

Personally, I would suggest (especially for beginners) not using the `$.get()` and `$.post()` methods but sticking with the fullblown `$.ajax()` and learning/understanding how to use it for both get and post. I say that because it has a more self-explanatory syntax.  I.e. each part has its name followed by a `:` then the part, instead of just having to know what order to place them in. It also results in much more readable code.

Also, to solve a caching issue, use `cache: false,` in your ajax call.  You can also append a parameter with a timestamp or random value.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I can't use a GET to start off through because the purpose of my code above is to action update.php with the change that I made to the database on getusers.php?q=John%Doe without being directed to that page.  That part works just fine, I just need that `getuser.php?q=John%Doe` to refresh at the end of all of this and that's the part I can't figure out.  I'm kind of looking for the same functionality as `window.location.reload();` but I can't do this because `ajaxtest.php` is the actual "page" that's loaded in the address bar.

Comment: @lordterrin, The beauty of doing it as above is you can easily change `type: 'GET',` to `type: 'POST',` without having to change anything else.

Comment: @lordterrin, Why do you want to "refresh" getuser.php? Is this another tab the user is looking at, or is this something only being called in the backend?  Either way, you can't "refresh" it this way. If its only being used in the backend by ajax, you don't need to "refresh" it, just to "call" it with ajax, as shown above.

Comment: @lordterrin, Its hard to understand your issue by your description, but it just dawned on me you're probably trying to describe a caching issue.  To make the browser stop caching the ajax response you would add `cache: false,` to the ajax call. I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation.  The user loads ajaxtest.php, which consists solely of a dropdown menu and a DIV.  Once a selection is made, this DIV is populated with getusers.php?q=[whatever name was just chosen.]  getusers.php mainly consists of a HTML table that is populated via an SQL query based on the person's name that was originally selected.  Once someone makes a CHANGE to this table, I want to refresh that page and **SHOW the change that the person has made**.  (E.g. - they enter 'this order is fine' in the Comments field.

Comment: Right now on getusers.php (inside the DIV on ajaxtest.php), there is a form that controls this `<form id="updateChanges" method="POST" action="update.php">` and a JavaScript file that waits for that form to be actioned, where the code in my original post lies.  Right now, the JS file is running perfectly - everything works, it updates my SQL database, but I can't figure out how to SHOW those changes that were made to the database because I can't just use `window.location.reload()` (as this reloads ajaxtest.php.  So I'm like 99% of the way there.. so close! But so far!

Comment: @lordterrin, You don't refresh the "page." You refresh the "div" or other element that holds the dropdown. Hence `$('txtHint').html(data);`.  Say your dropdown is in a Div with `id='mylist'` then do: `$('mylist').html(data);`  Its that simple.

Comment: @lordterrin, But this requires that the page you are calling via ajax returns the html that should go in the div.  "Returns" here means echos it out in php.

Comment: The AJAX call that I have works (I think) as intended... it ACTIONS update.php (the code that says "UPDATE table set foo = bar" etc), without redirecting me to that page, (which is what was happening before I put in the AJAX code.)  Once this has completed, I still physically see the main ajaxtest.php page (which is just the header with the dropdown,) and the getusers.php page (which contains the HTML table), but the change that I just made and successfully updated isn't visible to me unless I go to `localhost/ajaxtest.php` again and select that same user.